# How can I edit the properties of elements in my activity?

Tags: java, android

I am a complete noob and I am trying to decrease the padding of an image over time with my code. I have this so far:

```
    public void growPotato() {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long WorkingNum = 0;
    while(growing && WorkingNum > 5 ) {
        WorkingNum = 150 - ((System.currentTimeMillis() - base)/100);
        ImageView PotatoPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        PotatoPicture.SetPadding(WorkingNum);
    }
```

I get an error on the line after 'WorkingNum = 150 -' saying I am missing a ';' for 'LocalVariableDeclarationAssignment'. But my main problem is that I get the error: "The method  SetPadding(long) is undefined for the type ImageView"... How can I work around or fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
PotatoPicture.SetPadding(WorkingNum);
```

you should call:

```
PotatoPicture.setPadding(WorkingNum, WorkingNum, WorkingNum, WorkingNum)
```

Java is case sensitive, so setPadding and SetPadding aren't the same methods. Read API for more details: [ImageView.setPadding(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

In most Java naming conventions, local variables should start with lower case letter (or an underscore).

Comment: Thank you! My final code was: 'PotatoPicture.setPadding((int)WorkingNum, (int)WorkingNum, (int)WorkingNum, (int)WorkingNum);'

Do you have anything to say about the first error?

Comment: I have no idea what can cause such error, but I see that you've set WorkingNum to zero and then in next line you're checking if it's greater than 5. Don't you need a do/while loop instaed of while? [do-while and while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Oh wow... I'm very sorry... I get the error on the line after that.

Comment: I just moved the line before the loop and the error went away. But, I don't seem to see the potato growing... Do I need to refresh the display or something to see the change?

Comment: I'm not sure if setting setPadding in a main thread loop will work. To animate a view you can use View or [Property Animator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html). Check out also this [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html).

Comment: Thanks! Before seeing your comment I was trying to use what I have here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572727/taking-a-nap-using-threads-and-waits-sleep-in-android-activities