# Taking a Nap: Using Threads and 'Waits'/Sleep in Android Activities

Tags: java, android

Ok, I am making a basic app where there is a picture of a potato that will grow and shrink by the application editing the padding of the element. I am really new to Threads and I am for sure doing something wrong with the sleep/waits.

Here is my code; it is relatively self explanatory:

```
package com.Potato.growingpotato;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GrowScreen extends Activity {

    private Thread thread;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grow_screen);
        thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                growPotato();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_grow_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        handler.removeCallbacks(thread);
        handler.postDelayed(thread, 0);
    }

    public void HarvestPotato(View view) {
        ImageView ThePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ThePicture.setPadding(150,150,150,150);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void NapTime(int Time) { //Try to make the application sleep for 'Time'
          try {
              Thread.sleep(Time);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
    }

    public void growPotato() { //Fancy Padding manipulation 
        long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long WorkingNum = 0;
        ImageView PotatoPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
         do {
            NapTime(100);
            WorkingNum = 150 - ((System.currentTimeMillis() - base)/100);
            PotatoPicture.setPadding((int)WorkingNum, (int)WorkingNum, (int)WorkingNum, (int)WorkingNum);
        } while(WorkingNum > 5 );

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause(); 
        handler.removeCallbacks(thread);
    }
}
```

The application freezes after starting and it is a white screen. Eventually, the picture pops up at full size and so does the button; when the button is pressed, it freezes completely

Comment: Why dont you give try to alpha + scale animation?

Comment: what is the exact problem you facing

Comment: The application freezes after starting and it is a white screen. Eventually, the picture pops up at full size and so does the button; when the button is pressed, it freezes completely.